# In Ccnet, where is the variable $LastIntegrationCommit persisted?

Tags: git, cruisecontrol.net, ccnet-config

In the ccnet [documentation](http://www.cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/Git) there is a reference to a variable called ***$LastIntegrationCommit***.  This line is throwing an error since I had to do a filter-branch and crush a bunch of bad stuff.  I want to delete it, but can't seem to find it even by greping the directory.

---

**Checking for modifications**

Once the repository is initialized the "git fetch origin" command is issued to fetch the remote changes. Next, "git log ***$LastIntegrationCommit***..origin/$BranchName --name-status -c", is issued to get a list of commits and their changes, where **$LastIntegrationCommit** is the commit which was checked out the last time an integration was run. If the project has not yet been integrated, a "git log origin/$BranchName --name-status -c" command is issued instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is storesd in the state file for the project. It typically lives in the cruise control.net server directory (c:\program files\cruise control.net\server). The state file should be the same name as the project with the .state extension.

I've found that this file is read in at server start and, although persisted to disk, is not re-read; you'll need to stop and restart the service for the change to take affect.

Comment: can I just delete the state file?

Comment: Yes. But you'll need to restart the server for it to forget any settings. Obviously ccnet will recreate it on the next build.